# Having multiple outgoing IPs in IIS?

Tags: iis

As you know there is just one Outgoing IP on Windows Server 2008 R2 but I have 10 websites running on IIS virtual directories, also there are 10 different IPs on the server, now I want to do each website has different Outgoing IP at the same time. Is it possible? you know via HTTP get/post programmatically.

Also I've read below article but it is for setting-up one default Outgoing IP. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2386184

How about by programming? Is there any solution to send requests by a specific IP?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is:

```
httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback); 


 public IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
    {
        if (retryCount < 3)
            return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(servicePointIP), 0);
        else
            return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    }

 private string servicePointIP;
    public string ServicePointIP
    {
        get { return servicePointIP; }
        set { servicePointIP = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure one IP address or multiple IP addresses for the same site.  Likewise, you can configure one web site for one IP address or many web sites for one IP address.  The only restriction is when you use HTTPS.

This Microsoft article talks about how to configure an IP address to (each) web site.  Even though it says it is for Server 2003, the config hasn't changed much in the last 2 revisions. http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4b7db43-2e10-4939-b888-a7b439af7fef.mspx?mfr=true

---

In the article that you mentioned, it talked about using the NETSH command (shell) to set up one outgoing path (using the skipassource flag).  To use all IP addresses for outbound traffic, simply do the opposite:

```
Netsh int ipv4 add address <Interface Name> <ip address> skipassource=false
```

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2386184
- http://forums.iis.net/p/1183088/2002060.aspx

Comment: The problem is for outbounding IP, after configuration you can see your machine has just 1 outgoing IP and all websites with different IPs go outbound from one IP.

Comment: Have you tried removing all incoming routes (names, IP addresses, *, etc) except for the (single) IP address for each site?  What are you doing to detect this condition?